Qt Application breaking in disassembly code on debug start in my application and Qt example application
Testing Main Application
My Qt application has been running fine on my Windows 11 machine for almost two years since I took over development for it. Recently what's happened is that when I start the program in debug mode, it first breaks in disassembly code with the following exception trigger pop up message with the .show() member function is called:
The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception.
Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception at 0x772a1fdf, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0xbaadf00c, flags=0x0 (first chance).

The disassembler stops here:

Running the code after this exception is triggered launches the program, but the program will occasionally break in disassembler again and crash.
I am compiling with MSVC and I've tried a number of different compilers and have tried Qt versions 5.2.0, 5.14.1, and 5.15.2 and all produce the same error on Windows 11. I have also tried different combinations of Windows SDK packages, and all produce the same result. I have tried VS Build tools 2015, 2017, and 2019 with no change.
I ended up installing Windows 10 on another machine and ran the setup with Qt 5.14.1, MSVC compiler 15.9.28307.2094, and Windows 10 SDK 10.0.17763.132 where it runs as expected with no problems.
Qt Setup on my Win 11 machine:

My Qt Creator "About" window:

Testing Qt Default Application
This one has really confused me. I sought help from the Qt forums here and found I receive the same error when testing a default Qt example application. I am using Qt Creator as my build and debug tool. This is not an issue with the code. I created a new Qt project with the base code that is provided by default, and that gives me the same error:
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}


Testing Applications example in Qt Examples
Just as in my program, the "crash" occurs once the .show() function is called. In this case, it's mainWin.Show(). Stepping over/into that fails to disassembler:

and this is the stack trace:

Running in Release Mode

Start with debugging = same crash
Start with no debugging = no crash

Running in Debug mode

Same as above

So it looks like debug run is the issue here, I think.
And these are the buttons I am referring to when I say "start with debugging":

Things I have Tried

Completely reinstalling Qt
Completely reinstalling all Visual Studio development tools and compilers
Selecting "Ignore first change access violations" in CDB settings — with this, it eliminates the issue of the exception being caught at debug start, however entering a breakpoint during runtime causes the application to break into disassembler code once again:

        ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
0x772c8c00                   int     3
0x772c8c01  <+    1>         ret
0x772c8c02  <+    2>         int     3


The memory address you're trying to access 0xBAADF00C
is suspiciously close toe 0xBAAF00D. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak).
bad food") is used by Microsoft's LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED) to indicate uninitialised allocated heap memory when the debug heap is used.] . The problem is most likely in a piece of code of your own not QT. E.g. dereferencing an invalid pointer, trrying to access a deleted object.  In other words the location of the crash is a RESULT of an earlier error (not the cause)

If your default application has this problem I suspect you have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell is there any chance you installed MinGW binaries for Qt and have those in your path? Or perhaps some application you have installed uses MinGW Qt? My advice to begin is to search for Qt dlls on your PC. If you find additional Qt dlls add that information to your question.

@PepijnKramer  it is happening in QT example applications, not just my application as I state in the post and heading.
